# Name/alias a set of instructions in a polars logical plan?

Tags: python-polars

lets say i have a `pl.LazyFrame` that was created through a long chain of instructions. I want to display its logical plan simply as `'custom_name_lazyframe'` for debug purposes - say, i have 10 of those complicated `pl.LazyFrames` and i want to debug relations between them. Is there a way to do this, maybe creating some label for a part of a logical plan?
the way i imagine it is:

```py
import polars as pl
a = pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]}).with_row_count()
lazy1 = a.lazy().select(pl.all().first())
lazy2 = a.lazy().select(pl.all().last()-2)
result = lazy1.<label_logical_plan>('lazy1').join(lazy2.<label_logical_plan>('lazy2'), on='row_nr')
result
```

> INNER JOIN:
> LEFT PLAN ON: [col("row_nr")]
> LABEL: lazy1
> RIGHT PLAN ON: [col("row_nr")]
> LABEL: lazy2
> END INNER JOIN

here, <label_logical_plan> is the functionality im looking for. I understand that after optimizing the logical plan there could be nothing left of some sections, however, im not thinking about actually running code like that, its just for debugging the dependencies

Comment: I may be wrong but: looking at https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/55242df50c8b60cf458214960e942ea7abc7a72b/crates/polars-plan/src/logical_plan/format.rs#L51 it doesn't seem like it. I think it may need to be a feature request.